# Create a single pandas dataframe from multiple OHLCV dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a folder containing the S&P500 components historical intraday data (1 min freq), saved as single .parquet tables (500 files, 7.60GB total).

Every table has a datetime index and five columns ('Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'), but they all have different lenghts (it depends on their [IPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_public_offering)):

- if they begin with the same year, they may begin in different quarters
- if they begin with the same year-quarter, they may begin in different months
- if they begin with the same year-quarter-month, they may begin in different weeks
- if they begin with the same year-quarter-month-week, they may begin in different days
- if they begin with the same year-quarter-month-week-day, they may begin in different minutes

To test my portfolio strategy, I need to test my model on multiple assets at the same time, where the time is a common datetime index, row after row. I also need to use the groupby function (by year, quarter, month, week and day) to apply my model to different dataframe's slices.

What I want to do is to merge all these single dataframes in a single, bigger one, with a datetime index long enough to contain all the smaller indices. In this big dataframe, I want (I'm open to different solutions) the single assets as different columns, something like:

```
       Apple                             Amazon
       Open  High  Low  Close  Volume    Open  High  Low  Close  Volume
index
2002
.
.
.
2017
```

How can I merge all the dataframes while maintaining a common index between them?

My workstation has an i7 CPU (4C/8T) and 16GB of RAM, so I think that I could be able to load this big dataframe entirely in memory, but I have no idea if a solution like Dask can be more efficient. My problem with Dask is the poor documentations and lack of examples, I'm not a pro developer so it's not easy to implement it for me.

Comment: What have you done to merge them in Pandas so far, and what has been going wrong?

Comment: That is what I'm asking, I have no idea how to merge "horizontally" the single dataframes and how to set a single index for all of them.

Comment: Have you tried `dd.concat(..., axis=1)`?  If so, did you run into problems?

Comment: Yeah, to maintain the asset's name above it's relative subcolumns I used dd.concat([df1, df2,...,dfn], axis=1, keys=[asset1_name, asset2_name,...,assetn_name]). It works.
The only problem is that by doing so it changes the columns dtype from int32 to float64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code section below contains two functions. `df_sample()` creates a dataframe of a desired size, a starting point and column names. The function multiJoin() takes a pre-defined list of dataframes and joins them using any method available for [pandas Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join). With that setup, all you need to do is run `multiJoin(dfs = [df1, df2, df3], method = 'outer', names = ['Apple', 'Amazon', 'SomeOther'])` to obtain your desired result for the sample dataframes. And I've added a a function `newNames(df, sep, name1, name2)` to take care of the hierarchical column names:

```
Apple                           Amazon
Open  High  Low  Close  Volume  Open  High  Low  Close  Volume

# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

# Function for reproducible data sample
def df_sample(start, rows, names):
    ''' Function to create data sample with random returns

    Parameters
    ==========
    rows : number of rows in the dataframe
    names: list of names to represent assets

    Example
    =======

    >>> returns(rows = 2, names = ['A', 'B'])

                  A       B
    2017-01-01  0.0027  0.0075
    2017-01-02 -0.0050 -0.0024
    '''
    listVars= names
    rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=rows, freq='D')
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,200,size=(rows, len(listVars))), columns=listVars) 
    df_temp = df_temp.set_index(rng)
    #df_temp = df_temp / 10000

    return df_temp

colNames = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

# Reproducible dataframes
df1 = df_sample('1/1/2017', 150,colNames)
df2 = df_sample('2/1/2017', 150,colNames)
df3 = df_sample('3/1/2017', 150,colNames)

#%%

def multiJoin(dfs, method, names):
    """ Takes a pre-defined list of pandas dataframes and joins them
        by the method specified and available in df.join().
        This is a specific case for joining a bunch og OHLCV tables,
        so column names will overlap. You should therefore specify 
        a list for each dataframe to provide unique column names.

        Joining dataframes with different indexes will result in
        omitted and / or missing data.

        Using method = 'outer' will display missing values for mismatching dates.

        Using method = 'inner' will keep only dates where all dataframes have values and omit
                        all other.

    """

    # Isolate a df to join all other dfs on
    df_left = dfs[0]
    df_left.columns = [names[0]+ '_' + col for col in df_left.columns]
    df_other = dfs[1:]

    # Manage names
    names_other = names[1:]

    # Loop through list of dataframes to join on the first one,
    # and rename columns
    counter = 0
    for df in df_other:
        df.columns = [names_other[counter] + '_' + col for col in df.columns]
        df_left = df_left.join(df, how = method)
        counter = counter + 1

    return df_left

dfJoined_outer = multiJoin(dfs = [df1, df2, df3], method = 'outer', names = ['Apple', 'Amazon', 'SomeOther'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you run `dfJoined_inner = multiJoin(dfs = [df1, df2, df3], method = 'inner', names = ['Apple', 'Amazon', 'SomeOther'])`, you'll get:

[image]

**Addition after taking OP's comment into consideration:**

I've added a function that builds on [pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) that will give you hierarchical column names that should make the dataframes look just like you requested. Simply run `df_multi = newNames(df = dfJoined_inner, sep = '_')`.

```
def newNames(df, sep, name1, name2):
    """ Takes a single column index from a pandas dataframe,
        splits the original titles by a specified separator,
        and replaces the single column index with a 
        multi index. You can also assign names to levels of your new index
    """

    df_temp = dfJoined_inner
    sep = '_'

    single = pd.Series(list(df_temp))
    multi= single.str.split(sep, expand = True)

    multiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((multi[0], multi[1]), names = (name1, name2))


    df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_temp.values, index = df_temp.index, columns = multiIndex)

    return(df_new)


df_multi = newNames(df = dfJoined_inner, sep = '_', name1 = 'Stock', name2 = 'Category')
```

I'm using Spyder, so a screenshot of the dataframe in the variable explorer looks like this (notice the parenthesis in the column headers):

[image]

But if you run `print(df_multi.tail())`, you'll see that the column headers look just like you requested:

```
#Output
Stock       Apple                 Amazon                    SomeOther            
Category    Open High Low Close   Open High  Low Close      Open High  Low  Close   
2017-05-26   -92  140  47   -53    -73  -50  -94   -72        16  115   96     74
2017-05-27   169  -34 -78   120     46  195   28   186        -9  102  -13    141
2017-05-28   -98  -10  57   151    169  -17  148   150       -26  -43  -53     63
2017-05-29     1   87  38     0     28   71   52   -57         6   86  179     -6
2017-05-30   -31   52  33    63     46  149  -71   -30       -20  188  -34    -60
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about using '{asset_name}_Open' for columns name, but the results is practically the same I was looking for. If you know how to build a MultiIndex for columns, let me know.

Comment: I just added another function that will do exactly that. Now you can easily switch between the two different ways of naming your dataframes

Comment: @ilpomo, Did my last addition to the answer solve your problems?

Comment: Thanks for your incredible work, I really appreciated it. Thank you again for spending your time helping me.

Comment: I would like to contact you for a question, nothing about writing code or pay you for some work. Just a question about the "most logical practice" to solve a problem, because by looking your profile it looks like you could have the right answer. Just let me know if I can and how to contact you, thanks.

Comment: Sure, but I'm on vacation right now and nowhere near a computer (only phone). I'll contact you via SO chat in two weeks or so if that's not too late for you.

Comment: No problem man! Just write me when you come back! Have a nice vacation and thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've set up a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177076/room-for-vestland-and-ilpomo